# border between columns css

Tags: html, css

How do I draw a vertical border (newspaper-like) between the columns I've create?
I'm also open to writing this in css3.

```
    #contentBox 
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
}

#contentBox .article
{
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 50%;
    border-right: solid;
}
```

Then haml:

```
#contentBox
  .article
     %p text
  .article
     %p text
```

Comment: Where is the html you mention?

Comment: you can inspire yourself from http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns and use a gradient instead, you may use an absolute pseudo too, ... many ways actually that can be used

Comment: haml, yep, but here we have two empty blocks .... wich have an height of 0 ..nothing to see

Comment: @liroy that isn't HTML, but i've answered this for you below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as commented, 2 simple options:

**1) pseudo**

```css
   #contentBox {
     margin: 0 auto;
     width: 80%;
     overflow: hidden;
     /* wraps floatting element */
   }
   #contentBox .article {
     float: left;
     margin: 0;
     width: 50%;
   }
   /* test  */
   #contentBox .article {
     height: 300px;
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   }
   #contentBox .article:nth-child(1) {
     height: 200px;
   }
   /* pseudo option */
   #contentBox {
     position: relative;
   }
   #contentBox:before {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     border-left: 1px solid;
   }
```

```html
<div id='contentBox'>
  <div class='article'></div>
  <div class='article'></div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGyJLo

---

**2) background-image (linear gradient for test)** old solid method described [here](http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns)

```css
   #contentBox {
     margin: 0 auto;
     width: 80%;
     overflow: hidden;
     /* wraps floatting element */
   }
   #contentBox .article {
     float: left;
     margin: 0;
     width: 50%;
   }
   /* test  */
   #contentBox .article {
     height: 300px;
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);/*  to see just because they might have different height */
   }
   #contentBox .article:nth-child(1) {
     height: 200px;
   }
   #contentBox {
     background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 49.95%, black 49.95%, black 50%, transparent 50%)
   }
```

```html
<div id='contentBox'>
  <div class='article'></div>
  <div class='article'></div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VezWMe

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines to your css:

```
#contentBox .article
{   
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: #CCC;
    border-right-width: thin;
}
```

Comment: the border does appear but eliminates the columns--creating one long column instead of two.

Comment: Your div's are too wide with text in it. To fit in the contentBox, lower their percentage.

Comment: one more thing--how do I control the height of the border (make shorter than the overall div?)

Comment: Give it a top- and bottom padding (padding: 1% 0;)

Comment: It changes the entire div--not only the border...

Answer (score 1):

add box-sizing for the use of percentage widths and borders.

Then apply the border to the first article to split them with a single line.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#contentBox {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}
#contentBox article {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 600px; /* DEMO HEIGHT */
}
#contentBox article:first-child {
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="contentBox">
  <article>Change the HTML article to any tag/element you would like to use...</article>
  <article>Change the HTML article to any tag/element you would like to use...</article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the border is there just because its a block element so the border is displaying by the edge of screen you can do `display: inline`
 here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kpx1tqf6/1/